# Using Python Tracing To Signal To Higher-Level Methods

Tags: python-3.x, stack-trace, trace, inspect, traceback

I'm building a server where I'd like low level functions signal to higher level functions by calling them again. For instance:

```
def bar():
    print('hello')
    #run blah() again

def foo():
    bar()

def blah():
    foo()

blah()
```

Using traceback.extract_stack() or inspect.stack() methods which print out the past function calls come close to what I'm looking for, namely that when I get to bar(), I'd like to be able to know that originally, I called blah() to get this all going. However, I can't figure out a way to actually call blah() again. Btw I realize the above will be circular, just an example.

I also want to avoid passing any arguments back through the functions - I'm hoping there's some traceback/inspect/trace trick that will keep track of this all for me.

@ThomasK, a bit more background as to what I am up to (perhaps I'm thinking about this completely wrong): 1) I have a server that pulls information from a variety of sources (i.e. roots), does a bunch of calculations, and then sends out final data points (i.e. leaves) to clients that request it 2) The clients initiate the request to start off, saying 'I want X, Y, Z', and then the lazy server goes and gets it 3) subsequently the server keeps track of the roots, and when any of the 'roots' change, it automatically pulls on all the 'leaves' affected, sending out updates to the clients. In the above simplified example, bar() is the root, blah() is the leaf that sends out data to clients.

To make future development more flexible, I'd prefer to not hard code anything, and keep the basic premise that "okay, when your data changes, immediately go and tell everyone to re-request their data." Perhaps there's a pattern that encapsulates this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The idea of encapsulating code in functions is that the functions work the same way regardless of where they are called. Breaking that rule is likely to lead to massive headaches down the line.

Comment: @ThomasK pls see above edit/clarification

Comment: It sounds like a ZeroMQ PUB/SUB pattern would work. The server just pushes out updates, and clients get the updates they're subscribed to. ZeroMQ takes care of delivering the right messages to the right clients. It has excellent Python bindings (pyzmq), as well as for other languages. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out